# BCrypt TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I am trying to add a salt to my password but I have this error:

> (node:12652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'value' of undefined
>
> (node:12652) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>
> (node:12652) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.

my auth/index.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const myPlaintextPassword = 's0/\/\P4$$w0rD';
const someOtherPlaintextPassword = 'not_bacon';

const salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);

exports.modules = {
    salt
}
```

my controller:

```
const Users = require('../models/users');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const { salt } = require('../auth/index');

const getUsers = ((req,res) => 
    Users.findAll()
    .then((result) => { 
        res.json(result) 
    })
    .catch((error) => { res.json(error) })
    )

const addUsers = (async (req,res,next) => {
    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    let password = bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt.value);
    const data = {
        name,
        email,
        password
    }; 
    console.log(data);
    Users.create(data)
    .then((result) => { res.json(result) })
    .catch((error) => { res.json(error) });
});

module.exports = {
    getUsers,
    addUsers,
    Users
}
```

Comment: This error is likely happening when you try to call `salt.value`, so `salt` appears to be undefined. Are you sure you're importing what you think you are?

Comment: @nick no u can help me with this? 
I followed bcrypt's walkthrough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You exported a `salt` function. You are trying to access it's object which is of course undefined because this object has no property name `value`. So, it gives you a `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`error. `Salt` function already return a value.

And one more thing, it should be `module.exports` in `auth/index.js`.

You should return a value from function. This is how you can rewrite the whole process.

`index.js`

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const saltRounds = 10;
const myPlaintextPassword = 's0/\/\P4$$w0rD';
const someOtherPlaintextPassword = 'not_bacon';

module.exports.salt= function(){
return bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds); }
```

You may await for the salt function in the controller level.

`let password = await bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password, salt());`

That's it. Now, I think your code will work.

Comment: ty, but now i got other error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: data must be a string and salt must either be a salt string or a number of rounds

Comment: what is the output of `const val = bcrypt.genSaltSync(saltRounds);`

Comment: [Function] i use console.log(salt); and got function.

Comment: { salt: [Function] }

Comment: In that case, you can use `salt()` this way or `import salt`. Let me know what is happen

Comment: but what do i do with my import? const salt = require ('../ auth / index');

Comment: i try with this import and : (node:16408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: salt is not a function

Comment: No, check my latest code snippet . You should call it this way. 
 const {salt} = require ('../ auth / index');
then call the salt() function.

Comment: If you import the file `const salt = require ('../ auth / index');` this way, you have to call the function this way. salt.salt()

Comment: I started from there bro ;) I was dump too :p I would not mind if you give me a up vote too :p Happy Coding.